# Change part of url in href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of links on a page, which are created by a web-plugin:

```
 <a class="project-load" href="http://www.example.de/blog/portfolio/siteone/"></a>
 <a class="project-load" href="http://www.example.de/blog/portfolio/sitetwo/"></a> 
 <a class="project-load" href="http://www.example.de/blog/portfolio/sitethree/"></a>
 ...
 <a class="project-load" href="http://www.example.de/blog/portfolio/sitfour/"></a>
 <a class="project-load" href="http://www.example.de/blog/portfolio/sitfive/"></a>
```

Now, I want the url in href to:

```
http://www.example.de/service/siteone/
http://www.example.de/service/sitetwo/
http://www.example.de/service/sitethree/
...
http://www.example.de/sitefour/
http://www.example.de/sitefive
```

I found a lot of jQuery-Snippets, which are able to change the whole URL. But I only need to change part with different exceptions (sitefour, sitefive). Thanks for your help

Comment: use a regular expression replace or `split` and `join`.

Comment: What exactly do you want? what have you tried to accomplish it?

Comment: Not using the site so often lately, where are all the reasonable closing reasons?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mc2uA/)

```
// grab everything with class of project-load, loop over them
$('.project-load').each(function(){
  // grab the href
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  // change the href to something else
  var newhref = href.replace(/blog\/portfolio\//, '');
  // update href
  $(this).attr('href', newhref);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple replace would work:

```
$('a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', function(index,val){
    return val.replace('portfolio/','');
  });
});
```